# Как настроить Wireshark?

Tags: ssl, tls, wireshark

Из захваченного трафика получил значения:

Client Hello: **Random Bytes**

Server Hello: **Random Bytes**

Certificate: **x509af.subjectPublicKey**, **pkcs1.modulus**, **pkcs1.publicExponent**, **x509af.encrypted**

Client Key Exchange: **Encrypted PreMaster**

New Session Ticket: **tls.handshake.session_ticket**

Какие данные, из выше перечисленных, и в каком формате нужно сохранить в файлы, и куда прописывать пути к этим файлам в параметрах Transport Layer Security, что бы трафик начал расшифровываться?

P.S. Стандартную инструкцию по расшифровке, через Переменные среды, пробовал, безрезультатно.

Comment: Это невозможно, не просто так умные люди forward secrecy изобретали. Пока шифрующая программа не отдаст сама добровольно ключи для расшифровки, ничего не выйдет

Comment: @andreymal клиентская сторона, у меня на компе, ведь расшифровывает, значит должен быть способ. Разве значений тех параметров, что я написал не достаточно для расшифровки?

Comment: недостаточно, эта самая клиентская сторона должна добровольно предоставить ключи для расшифровки (ну или можно конечно найти и вытянуть ключ непосредственно из оперативной памяти компьютера, но это очень сложно и нужны соответствующие знания, которыми я не владею)

Comment: @andreymal wireshark не должен это уметь? Я создал клиента и сервер, со своим сертификатом. И не смог в wireshark увидеть свои расшифрованные сообщения, до тех пор пока не прописал путь к RSA PRIVATE KEY.

Comment: Не должен, wireshark просто перехватывает трафик, а не шерстит оперативку. Иметь RSA PRIVATE KEY обычно тоже недостаточно из-за этого самого forward secrecy